# Clang dumpPretty after rewrites

Tags: clang

I've tried to apply some rewrites to a function body and now want to print just that body in source form.  I've tried using the dumpPretty, but it seems to print the original source without my rewrites.  Does anyone have suggestions for the a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the source code, it appears that dumpPretty reconstructs the text from AST.  To transform the body this way, I must modify the AST directly.